# How to fix Cannot read property hasOwnProperty of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, object

How to fix Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined?

Using Angular.JS 1.3

Assigning response data in `$rootScope.settings` in **parentConroller**.

so the **rootScope** will be like this

```
    $rootScope.settings = api.data;

//sample
    $rootScope.settings:{
        "lastLogin":"2005-01-01",
        "isStudent": true,
        "assignedCourse": "['JAVA + DS']"
    }
```

And accessing the **$rootScope** data in anotherController.JS. But here I don't want my array inside string, so to remove double quotes, I tried below ways

**Attempt 1:**

```
 if($rootScope.settings.hasOwnProperty('assignedCourse')) {
        $rootScope.settings.assignedCourse = ['JAVA + DS']
    }
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$rootScope.settings.assignedCourse = JSON.parse(rootScope.settings.assignedCourse.replace(/'/g, '"'));

// giving me Error: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

Attempt 1 is working in the application, but its getting failed when i run karma debugger which is showing **TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined**

Literally don't know how to fix this issue. Struggling to fix more than a days

I've already gone through few SO's related to my issues. but don't get any better solutions

Side Note: currently using only plain old JavaScript, not es6 or updated version.

Comment: Your `$rootScope` object does not have a property [`settings`], therefore `undefined` is returned (`$rootScope.settings === undefined`). Trying to access a property on `undefined` leads to exactly your error. So the problem is not your array, but your `$rootScope` having a different value

Comment: yes,` "assignedCourse": "['JAVA + DS']"` this wat in my parent controller, and am trying to remove the double quotes to make it as array

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you may want to be using `angular.isDefined($rootScope.settings.assignedCourse)` instead of hasOwnProperty as it is likely syntactically closer to what you are testing for (defined value instead of property ownership)

Regarding attempt 1 failing in the test, settings is undefined. You may need to re-examine your test bed and ensure your scope is being initialized as you expect.

I recreated your attempt 2 successfully, I suspect something else is going on here and may be resulting from another line.

[image: example-code]

Comment: as you said , suppose if i want check the condition, should i do like this 

`if ($rootScope.settings.assignedCourse== "Java + DS"){
                console.log('say hi');
            }` ?

Comment: can you pls open a fiddle, so that i can understand clearly how you avoid double quotes and getting expected output

Comment: @Mr.Learner the double quotes are not the problem. `settings` is not a property on your `$rootScope`. You do not even get to the point where quotes are replaced in the array (because the array does not exist).

Comment: @knittl alright.. if not mind. pls share fiddle to understand visually what going on

Comment: For attempt one it's as simple as `rootScope.settings == undefined`. For the second, the provided code does not appear to be the issue. We would require more information to provide a solution.
I am curious if your attempt 2 is also failing in the tests for the same reason. if settings is undefined that would also cause problems (but your JSON parse would complain about the first token being a 'u' if that was the case)
Please update your question with the relevant information.